# NOAA Weather REST API causes error when requesting with curl

Tags: python, shell, rest, curl, noaa

I am trying to write a python program using NOAA's Climate Data Online REST Web Services (http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#data).  But, I am running into errors in my request responses.  When attempting a request with curl from command line I input:

```
curl -H "token:<MYTOKEN>" http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:22405&startdate=1999-10-05&enddate=1999-10-25
```

It returns this response:

```
[1] 24322
[2] 24323
[3] 24324
phil@philUbu:~$ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response><statusCode>400</statusCode><userMessage>There was an error with the request.</userMessage><developerMessage>Required parameter 'startdate' is missing.</developerMessage></response>
[1]   Done                    curl -H "token:..." http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND
[2]-  Done                    locationid=ZIP:22405
[3]+  Done                    startdate=1999-10-05
```

For some reason it thinks I am missing the startdate, but I have included it and it is in the proper format according to the documentation.  Does anybody have any ideas of what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The ampersands in the url are probably being parsed by your shell.  Put single quotes around it:

```
 curl -H "token:<MYTOKEN>" 'http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:22405&startdate=1999-10-05&enddate=1999-10-25'
```

Comment: That solved the issue, but now I am getting an empty response "{ }"

Comment: Nevermind, that got me on the right track.  Thank you so much for your help!